# How to add rows and copy cells to the added rows?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to create a macro, I got a sheet with hundreds of rows, from column A to AD.
I want to add after each row new row, move columns W to AD (23:30) from each row to the new rows I created. for example:
if I got this sheet:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 B B B B B
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 B B B B B
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 B B B B B
```

I want to create a macro that do this:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
B B B B B
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
B B B B B
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
B B B B B
```

I tried to do it own my own but I got stuck a lot.

Comment: Please show what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Can you please post the code you've tried? I'm going to assume you can add X amount of rows in between your data. Once you do, you can use this formula as an array: `=IFERROR(INDEX(I1:Q1,MATCH("*",I1:Q1,0)),"")` This would go in row two, column A.  Note: I'm assuming all your "B" data starts in Column I and doesn't extend past Q in any row (if it does, just adjust that part).  You can then drag this to the right until you start seeing blanks. (Or of course, just code the formula in VBA as an option).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub mover()
Dim lastRow
lastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
With lastRow
    For iRow = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty("A" & iRow) = False Then
            Range("W" & iRow & ":AD" & iRow).Select
            Selection.Cut
            Rows(iRow + 1).Select
            Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("A" & iRow + 1).Select
        End If
    Next iRow
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @justkrys! This works great but I need to keep columns A:U, in this code columns I:U stay in the same place.
sorry guys I dont post my code it is really not close to solve the problem

Comment: Thank you all, I just changed the range from W:AD to W:AQ in it worked fine!